# Revised CV soon after application, what to do

Tags: resume, job-search

I have recently graduated and started job hunting. I sent two application using a CV that I have now revised and improved quite significantly - I didn't have any project descriptions, just a generic link to my website and a specific link to a single project.  Being totally new to this kind of process I made a mistake the first time.

I know they already read the CV as I got a visit (very recently) to the only specific page that most likely come from those places. I feel like my revised CV is much better.

Is there anything I can do or is it too late?

Answer (score 4):

At this step, there isn't anything you can do. It would look bad to send an updated CV, as almost any "excuse" that you can make simply reflects badly on you. There are still a couple of good times to give them the new one:

- If a recruiter contacts you back and wants to setup an interview with the company, offer the new CV during your discussion with the recruiter.
- If the company contacts you back directly, bring in a physical copy (or several) of the updated CV when coming in for the interview.